# python statsmodel.api error: invalid syntax

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm using some simple syntax copied from a similar example, but I get an invalid syntax error on my 'y' variable and I don't understand why?

```
import pandas as pd
import os
df = pd.read_excel(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/ML_Wheat_Input.xlsx"))
df.head()

    Price   US S-to-U   World S-to-U    Date
0   203.41  0.451164    0.316851    2015-11-01
1   206.34  0.416095    0.318938    2015-10-01
2   193.97  0.409023    0.316268    2015-09-01
3   187.87  0.392560    0.309860    2015-08-01
4   207.38  0.361605    0.302978    2015-07-01

import statsmodels.api as sm

x = df[['US S-to-U', 'World S-to-U']
y = df[['Price']]

X1 = sm.add_constant(X)
est = sm.OLS(y, X1).fit()

est.summary()
```

Comment: Count the brackets on the line before.

Comment: square bracket missing you should have noticed it from intellisense not even after compiling.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I can't see the wood from the trees. Thank you.